# how to implement paypal payment button in an existent  sign up form

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

I have a really strong feeling that this question will either be closed or not answered at all because I've seen many paypal questions not answered on the web :D

but I'm ready to take the risk and I'm gonna ask it here because paypal forum is inactive and I have googled for months and did not see anything like my question

I have an existent sign up form and login form on my site, I just wanna add a paypal subscribe  to my existent forum i don't want to re-write the whole thing, I don't know if have to use ipm or api or simply the html code whatever...

i can't use sandbox to test my code (i don't know why) so i rely on you to give me a working example or some kind of tutorial, I have seen most of them (if not all) and no tutorial teach what i need to know

the simplest thing would be to remove my sign up button, and use paypal subscribe button instead

here's my sign up form (I'm using smarty template just for now, I'm gonna be using another template in the future)

```
        {assign var='required_fields' value=$userquery->load_signup_fields()}
    {assign var='custom_field' value=$userquery->custom_signup_fields}

    {if $mode == 'signup_success'}
    <div class="signup_con" style="margin-top:20px;">
    <div class="simple_container">
            {if $udetails.usr_status !='Ok'}
                {lang code='signup_success_usr_ok'}
            {else}
                {lang code='signup_success_usr_emailverify' assign='signupsuccessusremailverify'}
                {link name='login' assign='login_link'}
                {$signupsuccessusremailverify|sprintf:$login_link}
    {/if} </div>
    {else}    
    <div class="signup_left full_round_10">
        <h2>{lang code='user_mem_login'}</h2>
        {lang code='if_you_already_hv_account'}
        <div class="signup_container">
            <form name="login_form" id="login_form" method="post" action="" >
              <label for="login_username" class="label">{lang code='username'} : </label>
                <div class="input_container">
                    <input name="username" type="text" id="login_username" size="30" >
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
              <label for="login_password" class="label">{lang code='password'} : </label>
                <div class="input_container">
                <input name="password" type="password" id="login_password" size="30" >
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <label for="" class="label">&nbsp;</label>
                <div class="input_container">
                <input type="submit" name="login" class="send_msg"value="{lang code='login'}" >
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div align="center"><a href="{$baseurl}/forgot.php">{lang code='user_forgot_password'}</a> | <a href="{$baseurl}/forgot.php">{lang code='user_forgot_username'}</a></div>
            </form>
      </div>

       {lang code='signup_message_under_login'}
    </div>
    <div class="signup_right full_round_10">
        <h2>{lang code='new_mems_signup_here'}</h2>
        {lang code='register_as_our_website_member'}
        <div class="signup_container">
            <form name="login_form" id="login_form" method="post" action="" >
                {foreach from=$required_fields item=field}
                    <label for="{$field.id}" class="label">{$field.title}</label>
                    <div class="input_container">
                    {if $field.hint_1}
                    <div class="hint">{$field.hint_1}</div>
                    {/if}
                    {ANCHOR place=$field.anchor_before}{$formObj->createField($field)}{ANCHOR place=$field.anchor_after}
                    {if $field.hint_2}
                    <div class="hint">{$field.hint_2}</div>
                    {/if}
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>


                {/foreach} 

                <!-- Loading Custom Fields -->
                {foreach from=$custom_field item=field}
                    <label for="{$field.id}" class="label">{$field.title}</label>
                    <div class="input_container">
                    {if $field.hint_1}
                    <div class="hint">{$field.hint_1}</div>
                    {/if}
                    {ANCHOR place=$field.anchor_before}{$formObj->createField($field)}{ANCHOR place=$field.anchor_after}
                    {if $field.hint_2}
                    <div class="hint">{$field.hint_2}</div>
                    {/if}
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>


                {/foreach} 

                <!-- Loading Captcha if anny -->
                {assign var=captcha value=func->get_captcha()}
                {if $captcha} 
                    {if $captcha.show_field}
                        <label class="label" for="verification_code">Verification Code</label>
                            {load_captcha captcha=$captcha load=field field_params = ' id="verification_code" '}
                       <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    {/if}
                    <label class="label">&nbsp;</label>
                    <div class="input_container">
                        {load_captcha captcha=$captcha load=function}
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                {/if}
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div align="center">
                    <input name="agree" type="checkbox" id="agree" value="yes" checked="checked" />
                    {lang code='user_i_agree_to_the' assign='user_i_agree_to_the'}
                    - {$user_i_agree_to_the|sprintf:$cbpage->get_page_link(3):$cbpage->get_page_link(2)}</a>
              </div>
                <label for="" class="label">&nbsp;</label>
                <div class="input_container">
                <input type="submit" name="signup" class="send_msg" value="{lang code='signup'}" style="margin-top:10px" />
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    {/if}
    </div>    
    <div class="clearfix"></div

>
```

if you need my login as well, I'll edit the question and I'll add that, you can do anything you want to do, you can use Ipn, api, or whatever...

Thanks in advance :D

**EDIT**

@ROBERT:

as far as i know website payment pro and express checkout is used for selling stuff online right? if so, i don't need them, sir i need a subscription button, and I'll follow any example to get it, anything that comes to your mind or any link that you find

thank you for saying that paypal is a big company, now you know my problem lol, it's not like facebook, if you want to do this, you use this api, if you want to do that you use that api, paypal is not like that, it has so many stuff, paypal is so confusing

this is my first project where i have to use paypal, i keep reading articles, every articles is totally different than the other and none of them say what i need to know :D

How do i plan to handle their returns back to my site? and do i need to collect info from people?

I don't need to collect info, you see i have a sign up form, so people are arleady filling their info which is stored in my db, even their email address of course so why would i need to collect anything at all through paypal?

when you sign up to my site, you receive a mail saying that u have signed up, welcome...
I **THINK** that the simplest thing would be to remove the sign up button, put the paypal subscription button and when the payment is made they receive the confirmation email that they have signed up

since i am no pro in paypal world, i would like to go for the simplest way to get the job done, which is to use the basic html code for subscription button and the payment is made the confirmation email will be sent

again it's is just a suggestion, i don't know if and how it's possible... ?

if not I'll go for any solution that you suggest as long as the job gets done

Comment: Do not post your login information.  That is not necessary to help you.  Never let random folks on the internet have access to your PayPal account.

Comment: @Brad: ok I won't but I'll leave my sign up page because people can directly play with it lol ...btw i'm not afraid of hackers :D i mean they don't know what website i own :D

Comment: i am really shocked that i haven't received any answers yet coz this is supposed to be a very easy question for an experienced paypal developer...if i can't receive answers here, I won't receive answers anywhere else. coz I know that this is the best programming forum ever, so i'm really really shocked!  i have seen harder questions solved in 2 minutes!

Comment: you haven't received any answers because this question is quite terrible.  You can improve it by being much more clear as to what your question is.  As it stands now, my read is that you want someone to do this for you, and that you have no specific question.

Comment: @Brad: my question is specific sir: how to implement paypal payment button in an existent sign up form? and no, i can do it by myself, i have hands and a brain, if someone explains how, but i don't someone to answer me : use ipn or see paypal documentation, paypal has a very huge documentation, i have received answers like: you have to use api before..I hate these answers all i want is specific answer or a link for a tutorial and I'll do everything by myself

Comment: I still have no clue what you want. Yes, I get the picture, you want to stick a subscription inbetween your signup and signup-success pages. But what information do you want to collect? Which PayPal product do you want to integrate? PayPal is the company. Website Payments Standard, Website Payments Pro, Express Checkout (and others) are the products.

Comment: What information do you collect from people when they sign up and how do you plan on putting PayPal 'inbetween' there? You do know you'll need to redirect people to the PayPal website to agree to the subscription charges? How do you plan to handle their returns back to your site?

Comment: @Robert: sir i added some explanations. if you need anything else I'll add anything lol :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, having read your revised question, and taking into account your limited experience, I'd say you're probably better off placing the subscription button *after* the sign up page(s).
That way, all you need to do is paste in some simple PayPal HTML code, rather than integrate the button (and checkout flow) mid flow of your signup page.

For a simple PayPal Subscription (HTML-based = Website Payments Standard), just visit [here](http://paypal.com/buttonfactory) and select all the required options.
Once created, modify the HTML as needed. E.g., if you want to dynamically alter the price, simply adjust the values for a1 / a2 as needed.

See also [this](https://merchant.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_html) variables for more available parameters you can use.
Note: with Website Payments Standard, all parameters are usually POST'ed as 'hidden' input fields ()